# Soft credit search without my permission

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-score, credit-report

I recently bought a wallpaper sample for £1.99 online from a well known decorator company. I did not apply for credit for this purchase and paid the full amount at the time of purchase. I have since checked my credit report and this company has carried out a soft credit search on my account on the same date I made this purchase and without my permission or any reason to do so. What can I do about this? This is the first and only time I have ever made a purchase with this company

Comment: Are you sure they didn't have your permission? It may have been buried somewhere in the terms of service that you "agreed" to when you hit purchase.

Comment: Also: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/35239/can-a-company-run-a-credit-check-on-me-without-my-permission

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about the UK, but in the US, soft credit searches are available for anyone who cares to pay for it, no permission needed.
They have zero impact on your credit history, and they are typically done because the  company thinks about offering (soliciting) you a loan or a credit card (even though you never asked for it). They basically do mass soft credit checks, and then offer something to the people looking low risk.

That would mean there is nothing you can do, but there is also nothing you need to do. It's just part of how the finance industry works.

Again, I am talking about the US, under the assumption that this is quite similar in the UK - but I might be wrong.

Comment: It seems like you need permission first in the UK: https://www.equifax.co.uk/resources/loans_and_credit/soft-credit-searches-explained.html   ... Op might consider contacting the credit bureau and see if they have any recommendations.

Comment: I don't see anything mentioned so. Note the page is titled 'soft credit explained', but talkes about 'hard' credit checks up to the last paragraph.

Comment: There's a big difference between a bulk search and a specific pull, even when both are soft.  Also, it's possible to opt out of bulk searches (prescreening opt out).  It seems to be quite a coincidence that the soft pull came on the same day that OP placed his first order, if it were indeed a bulk search.

Answer (score 0):

Soft inquiries occur when businesses, such as lenders, insurance companies, or credit card companies, check your credit to pre-approve offers.

Soft inquiries aren't linked to a specific application for new credit and these inquiries have no effect on your credit score as they are never considered as a factor in credit scoring models.

This should help.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the laws and/or terminology are different in the UK, but here in the US:

"Done without your permission" is pretty much the definition of a soft credit check. A "hard check" is made when you apply for a loan or a credit card. A "soft check" is most other checks on your credit rating. Most soft checks are because someone is considering offering you a loan or credit card. I don't know about you, but at least once or twice a weak I get a letter in the mail offering me a new credit card. Banks and stores do this routinely. They check the credit rating of everyone they know about, pick out those whose credit rating is high enough to meet their criteria, and send these people loan offers.

So you bought something from this company. They now know you exist. They added your name to thousands or millions of other customers, ran credit checks, and they'll offer some of those people -- maybe including you, maybe not -- credit cards or special financing deals or whatever.

What can you do about it? Not much. Why would you want to do anything about it? Why do you care? So someone checked your credit rating. If they decide to offer you a credit card and you don't want it, then ... don't sign up. Soft credit checks don't affect your credit rating, so it doesn't hurt you any.